# Accessible preview, but inaccessible website

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, website

I'm wondering if there is a way to access to a website whose preview is readable (see figure and link below).

http://amslaurea.unibo.it/1129/1/martelli_chiara_tesi.pdf

[image]

Comment: The “preview” is actually whats in the search engine’s index. You cannot access that. However, cache services are available on the web.

Comment: Hello @DanielB can you suggest me one of them in order to access to the above website please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something went wrong with the website, although its preview still exists
on the search engine.

You may still find the PDF file in the
[Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20181101110936/http://amslaurea.unibo.it/1129/1/martelli_chiara_tesi.pdf)
and can download it from there.

The Wayback Machine is the solution for many websites that disappear.

Comment: Hi @harrymc thank you a lot for your useful answer.